React Native Image flickering
Here's a link showing the flickering
Issue
I've been trying to build an app that allows users to swipe on clothes sort of like a Tinder-like experience and I've been having issues with the images flickering whenever I swipe on the top card and the card gets replaced the next card. Essentially after the animation finishes, the previous card flashes for a brief second before I am able to swipe on the next card. I believe the issue is which how I manage the swapping animation as I essentially just increment the index of my array holding the image url and other information.
What I've tried

Using additional states to ensure that the swiping animation is completely over before changing the index. This sadly didn't change anything

Playing around with the opacity of the top card once it has been swiped. All this did was make it flash white instead of the previous image which doesn't really solve the issue

Tried fetching and loading all the images before hand to ensure that the images weren't being fetched more than once but that didn't solve anything either


Simplified Code
const AnimatedView = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(View);

export default function App() {
    const data = Object.values(clothesJson[0].data); 
    const {width: screenWidth} = useWindowDimensions();

    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
    
    var currentCard = data[currentIndex];
    const nextCard = data[(currentIndex+1)%data.length];

    const translateX = useSharedValue(0);
    const contextX = useSharedValue(0);
    const rotation = useDerivedValue(() => interpolate(
        translateX.value,
        [0, screenWidth],
        [0, 20]
    ) + 'deg');

 
    
    //Rotation animation when swipping for main card
    const cardStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        return {
            transform: [
                {
                    translateX: translateX.value
                },
                {
                    rotate: rotation.value
                },
            ],
 
            
        };
    });

    //Growing animation for next card 
    const nextCardStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        return {
            transform: [
                {
                    scale: interpolate(
                        translateX.value,
                        [-1.5*screenWidth, 0, 1.5*screenWidth],
                        [1, 0.95, 1]
                    ),
                },
                 
            ]
            )
        };
    });

    //Swipping logic
    const swipe = Gesture.Pan()
        .onBegin(() => {
            
            contextX.value = translateX.value;
        })
        .onChange((event) => {
            translateX.value = event.translationX + contextX.value;

        })
        .onEnd((event) => {
            //Swipe Speed < 800 && Amount card moved < 150
            
            if (Math.abs(event.velocityX) < 800 && Math.abs(event.translationX) < 150) {
              translateX.value = withSpring(0, {mass:0.5});
            } else {
                
                //Check to see which way card should be hidden
                translateX.value = withSpring(
                    1.5 * screenWidth * Math.sign(event.translationX),
                    {mass:0.15},
                    
                    () => {
                        //I think the issue is in this logic here
                        runOnJS(setCurrentIndex)(((currentIndex + 1)%data.length));
                        translateX.value = 0;
                        
                    }
                )
                        
                
                
            }

        })

        
    return (
        <View style={styles.pageContainer}>
            
            <View style={styles.nextCard}>
                <AnimatedView style={[nextCardStyle, styles.nextCard]}>
                    <ClothesCard clothesData={nextCard}/>
                </AnimatedView>
            </View>

            <GestureHandlerRootView>
            <GestureDetector gesture={swipe}>
                <AnimatedView style={[cardStyle, styles.animatedCard]}>
                    <ClothesCard clothesData={currentCard}/>
                </AnimatedView>
            </GestureDetector>
            </GestureHandlerRootView>
                
        </View>
    );

}


